# Preencher modal com dados do Bd em PHP

Tags: php, bootstrap-3, jquery-remodal

Estou com dificuldades em preencher um modal com dados vindo de uma consulta sql.

Eu tenho uma lista com todos os produtos. Nessa lista eu tenho um botão que ao ser clicado deve abrir um modal com os detalhes do produto.

Botão:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-mini" data-toggle="modal" onclick="detalhesProduto(' + retorno[i].id + ')">+ Detalhes</button>
```

Esse button passa o id do produto para a function abaixo:

```
function detalhesProduto(id) {
    alert(id);
    $('#myModal').modal('show');        
}
```

Nesse caso, eu tenho uma outra function que conecta e varre o banco , onde pego o id do produto.

Do jeito que está ai, eu clico no botão é aberto um dialog com o id do produto selecionado, logo em seguida abre o dialog, porém não sei como preencher ela com os dados... que nesse caso, se preenchesse pelo menos o id eu já me virava com o resto.

Meu modal está assim:

```
<div class="modal fade bs-detalhes-modal-lg" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Detalhes</h5>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" id="conteudoModal">
                   .............. 
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-mini" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>                        
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Poderiam me dar uma ajuda nisso?

Comment: Não entendi essa parte: "Do jeito que está ai, eu clico no botão é aberto um dialog com o id do produto selecionado, logo em seguida abre o dialog"

Comment: @Lucas é que quando clico no botão, eu já estou pegando o ID co produto ... e esse ID eu coloquei em um alert para ver se estava mudando conforme eu clico em outro produto de minha lista. Ou seja, o dialog ou modal... abre... apenas não sei como pegar os dados do produto e colocar nesse modal.

Comment: Hum sim. Teria que fazer em Ajax

Comment: Entendi, e como eu faria isso? Eu tenho um ajax que busca todos os meus produtos e preenche a lista que falei. Peguei alguns exemplos na net e não consegui sucesso em preencher o modal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolvido:

```
function detalhesProduto(id) {
    $('#myModal').modal('show');
    $("#conteudoModal").load('detalhaProduto.php?id=' + id);
}
```

Comment: Que bom. Marque esta resposta como certa então (clicando no check ao lado da resposta)